# How can I hide just the custom gizmo icon on with a checkbox instead of all gizmo's as my script does?

Tags: python, scripting, gizmo

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import StringProperty, IntProperty, BoolProperty
from bpy.types import (
    GizmoGroup,
)

# CUTOM PANEL IN PROPERTIES OUTPUT PANEL
class CUSTOM_PT_menupanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Output Properties of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Test"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "output"    

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene

        row = layout.row() 
        row.prop(scene, "gizmo_show_hide")  

#SCREEN OVERLAY GIZMO
class Camera_overlay(GizmoGroup):
    bl_idname = "Gizmo_Icon"
    bl_label = "Gizmo"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_options = {'PERSISTENT', 'SCALE'}

    def draw_prepare(self, context):    
        region = context.region
        self.my_gizmo.matrix_basis[0][3] = region.width - 40
        self.my_gizmo.matrix_basis[1][3] = 40 

    def setup(self, context):
        mpr = self.gizmos.new("GIZMO_GT_button_2d") 
        mpr.icon = 'OUTLINER_OB_CAMERA'
        mpr.draw_options = {'BACKDROP', 'OUTLINE'} 
        self.my_gizmo = mpr 

#GIZMO SHOW AND HIDE FUNCTION
def update_func_gizmo(self, context):    
        areas = context.workspace.screens[0].areas        
        for area in areas:
            for space in area.spaces:
                if space.type == 'VIEW_3D':   
                    space.show_gizmo^= True                                   

        return{'FINISHED'}

#CHECKBOX GIZMO BOOL  
bpy.types.Scene.gizmo_show_hide = BoolProperty(
    name="Gizmo Hide",
    description="Check Box to Show And Hide Gizmo",
    default = True, update = update_func_gizmo)

#CLASS LIST                        
classes = (

    CUSTOM_PT_menupanel,
    Camera_overlay,  
)

#REGISTER AND UNREGISTER CLASSES
register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I found an answer to my solution after hours of playing around fiddling with something I know very little about but feeling pleased with myself, now just need to get rid of this headache!

Answer (score 1):

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import StringProperty, IntProperty, BoolProperty
from bpy.types import (
    Operator,
    GizmoGroup,
)

# CUTOM PANEL IN PROPERTIES OUTPUT PANEL
class CUSTOM_PT_menupanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Output Properties of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Test"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "output"    

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene

        row = layout.row() 
        row.prop(scene, "gizmo_show_hide") 


#SCREEN OVERLAY GIZMO
class Camera_overlay(GizmoGroup):
    bl_idname = "Gizmo_Icon"
    bl_label = "Gizmo"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_options = {'PERSISTENT', 'SCALE'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        scene = context.scene
        if scene.gizmo_show_hide:
            return False
        else:
            return True    

    def draw_prepare(self, context):    
        region = context.region
        self.my_gizmo.matrix_basis[0][3] = region.width - 35
        self.my_gizmo.matrix_basis[1][3] = 40 

    def setup(self, context):
        mpr = self.gizmos.new("GIZMO_GT_button_2d") 
        mpr.icon = 'OUTLINER_OB_CAMERA'
        mpr.draw_options = {'BACKDROP', 'OUTLINE'} 
        self.my_gizmo = mpr 


#CHECKBOX GIZMO BOOL  
bpy.types.Scene.gizmo_show_hide = BoolProperty(
    name="Gizmo Hide",
    description="Check Box to Show And Hide Gizmo",
    default = True)

#CLASS LIST                        
classes = (

    CUSTOM_PT_menupanel,
    Camera_overlay, 

)

#REGISTER AND UNREGISTER CLASSES
register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: As well as script an explanation of what you have done would be handy.  Similarly for question.  Would recommend naming the toggle say `gizmo_show` and simply `return scene.gizmo_show` in poll.

Comment: Taken on board batFINGER and agreed that it's not only my python skills(lack of) that needs improving! I was a little over excited that this old one here managed to solve my own problem and forgot to list what i had added/changed/deleted.